# Javascript url code to hover all

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a code I can enter in a URL to alter a website. The website has images and start a preview when you hover over the image with the cursor. So my question is can you send java script code in the URL to hover over all images to make all images show previews at the same time?
I noticed this code for their mouse over

```
onmouseover="startThumbChange(7901031, '49992710857901031', 16, 
'http://thumb1.cdn1a.image.websitename.com/videos/201212/06/7901031/240x180/');"
onmouseout="endThumbChange('49992710857901031');" />
```

or is this not possible?
(meaning it will only work if injecting java script with each image specifically?)

im guessing something like this
`javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("img")` or
`javascript:document.srartThumbChange(document.getElementsByTagName("img"))`

need help coding, not too familiar with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible! 
Using `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` you can loop over all images. You then need to check whether the mouseover attribute contains `startThumbChange` and then use JavaScript `eval` for example to run that function. You can run your complete code by putting it on one line and add `javascript:` before it, then paste it in your browser bar. Let me know if you need any more help!

**Update with example code:**

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
    imgs[i].onmouseover();
}
```

And to paste in your browser:

```
javascript:var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {imgs[i].onmouseover();}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6ZS3/1/

**Another update with a fix for the specified website**

I'm not sure why, but it seems on some websites the `onmouseover` can only be read as an `attribute` while on others only as an `event`. Perhaps someone else can shine some light on that, but at least this works for your goal :)

```
javascript:var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {eval(imgs[i].getAttribute("onmouseover"))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
but in my example it does have the `startThumbChange`
would that matter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just meant that you'd have to check if it contains the function you want to run (`startThumbChange`) if you only want to run that function of every image. You could leave that check out and just run the function of every `onmouseover` attribute of every image, but then you perhaps run functions you wouldn't want to as well. If you need more specific help I'd need the website you're referring to I think.

Comment: can you give me example of how it should look like to start the onmouseover for all images, i am sure that would work

Comment: yes that is what i am looking for, but the url version doesn't seem to be working. i tried an alert to test it and it works. maybe something wrong? hopefully the startThumbChange isn't messing it up

Comment: I made it work the way I originally intended it, see my updated post :)

Comment: Glad to help! I hope someone could give an answer to the issue I mentioned in my last update, very weird.